# IIS 10 SignalR config

Tags: iis, websocket, signalr, blazor

I have been developing an Blazor WASM app. Everything has been working fine on my local machine. However, once I deployed out the my Windows 2019 server running IIS 10 my browser cannot establish a web socket connection.

Currently in chrome I am getting a 101 status when trying to connect to my hub. However, that request always says pending.

Things I've done

- Enabled Websocket protocol in Server features
- secured the site with SSL
- I bound the site to 443 for ssl

If there is anything else I can do please let me know.

Comment: Refer to the documentation to configure websocket: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket#how-to-configure-websocket

Comment: @Theobald Du I have also done that.